# batch file to copy files from one folder to another

Tags: windows, batch-file

My scanner software puts it's file into `YYYY_MM_DD` subfolders in `C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Enrico\Eigene Dateien\Eigene Bilder\MP Navigator EX`. The files are all JPEG files.

Now I need to copy them out of the virtual machine, into a shared drive which is called `E:`.

I would like to copy the subfolders into the shared drive, so that I have those date folders there. If a new picture is added to today's folder, it should be copied as well.

On Linux, I would just use `rsync -avE` for this.

How can I do this with a plain batch file in XP and 7?

Comment: The third paragraph confuses me. Do want to **copy** or **move** the pictures?

Comment: Just copy, move is a little too risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xcopy` to copy entire directories (including subdirectories).

The syntax is:

```
xcopy source destination /S
```

where the `/S` switch includes non-empty directories (`/E` copies empty directories as well).

There are a couple of switches that serve as a backup solution:

- `/M` copies only changed files (archive attribute set) and unsets the attribute.
- `/D` copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) which is the microsoft equivalent to rsync.
To get the same result as `rsync -avE /source /dest` use the following command:

```
robocopy source dest /e
```

To run `rsync -avE --delete` you can directly use `robocopy /mir`.

Comment: This is also neat. I assume that this preferred over old xcopy?

Comment: As much as rsync is sometimes preferred to cp under *NIX systems :) It can resume transfers but doesn't support Volum Shadow Copy altough it can be used against an existing shadow copy. tl;dr is "xcopy < robocopy < rsync" feature-wise

Comment: It looks nice indeed. The tl;dr is not really needed for a two sentence comment … are are we in the flutter age now? ;-)

Comment: Sorry I can't revert that. I was maybe put off but my dislike for comments due to their lack of formatting possibilities and the fact you can't edit them afterwards, I'd prefer to have the same tools as in an answer but in a smaller font.